# OpenVPN won't connect to my IPv6 address (write UDP: unknown error code=10051)

Tags: linux, openvpn, ipv6

I have a problem with my VPN. I have recently gotten an IPv6 address and wanted to use that for OpenVPN.
I can connect if I use my IPv4 address instead which makes me think I have probably done something wrong or it isn't supported yet.

Below you can find my server.conf and client.ovpn:

server.conf:

```
  port 1194
  proto udp6
  dev tun-ipv6
  
  local 2a0a:51c0:0000:0227:0000:0000:0000:0002
  ca /path/to/ca.crt
  cert /path/to/server.crt
  key /path/to/server.key
  dh /path/to/dh.pem
  crl-verify /etc/openvpn/server/crl.pem
  
   server 10.132.178.0 255.255.255.0
   server-ipv6 fdbc:291a:f690:3a84::/64
   push "redirect-gateway ipv6 def1"
   push "route-ipv6 ::/0"
   push "route-metric 2000"
   
   push "dhcp-option DNS 2001:1608:10:25::1c04:b12f"
   push "dhcp-option DNS 2001:1608:10:25::9249:d69b"
   duplicate-cn
   cipher AES-256-CBC
   tls-version-min 1.2
   tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA256
   auth SHA512
   auth-nocache
   keepalive 20 60
persist-key
persist-tun
compress lz4
daemon
askpass /etc/openvpn/server/pass.txt
user nobody
group nobody
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 4)
```

client.ovpn:

```
client
dev tun-ipv6
proto udp6

remote 2a0a:51c0:0000:0227:0000:0000:0000:0002 1194

ca "path to CA"
cert "path to client cert"
key "path to client key"

cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
auth-nocache
tls-version-min 1.0
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA256
remote-cert-tls server

resolv-retry infinite
compress lz4
nobind
persist-key
mute-replay-warnings
verb 4
register-dns
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `ping`ing or `tracert`ing the server (after permitting ICMP on the firewall)?

Comment: I have tried pinging it. The IPv6 address is not pingable (why did I not do this earlier?).

Comment: And `tracert`? Where does it stop?

Comment: `tracert` stops at my IPv6 gateway address (request timed out after that).

Comment: *after permitting ICMP on the firewall*

Comment: Fire up tcpdump/wireshark. Set capture filters for ipv6 udp/1194 and attempt to connect.  If you don't see anything, it is likely some firewall or networking issue.

Comment: Tcpdump didnt show any incoming packages on UDP port 1194.